# How to debug jruby application in VS Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, jruby, vscode-debugger

I am using VS Code to debug my Rails Application and there are already a lot of blog posts about how to setup VS Code for debugging rails applications. This is working pretty well so far.

But now I have to debug a Rails Application depending on jruby and I can't figure out how to setup VS Code to debug this kind of application. I am pretty sure that this is possible but I don't know how.

I am using VS Code (v. 1.54.1) on my Ubuntu 20.04; using rvm to install the jruby version

```
rvm install jruby-9.2.10.0
```

My gemfile base information is

```
gem 'rails' , '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'jruby-jars', '9.2.10.0'
gem 'warbler', '>= 2.0.5'
```

What kind of debug gems are necessary to start debugging and how to setup the launch.json?

Many Thanks